# Can I turn on AdSense to my app after publishing it on the play store?

Tags: android, publish, adsense

I have published my app to the play store without turning on the AdSense account (No ads). But I want to turn on it now. Can I do that?

Comment: You submited your app with Admob test keys ?

Comment: No, I just submit by selecting no ads, when I publish my app on play store.

Comment: Google Mobile Ads SDK is integrated ?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything until now. I want to know whether I can integrate AdSense to my app or not after publishing it as it does not contain any ads in the app.

Comment: Actually I didn't publish my app till now, I'm going to publish it by ticking no ads in the app. But after 2 weeks having sufficient amount of crowd, I want to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Your published app will not receive any ads now.

To do that you are needed to resubmit your app after integrating [Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) on it and complete implementation.

Comment: By doing so my previous app downloads and reviews would disappear?

Comment: Even if I publish my app by ticking that app not containing any ads.